# Edit admin email template for new user registrations

Tags: users, emails, authentication-authorization

How do I edit the default email that gets sent to admin upon new user registration? I presume this is being managed by LoginToboggan because its being referenced in the email body text:

> UserName has applied for an account.
>
> http://example.com/user/XX/edit
>
> The user has automatically received the permissions of the **LoginToboggan**
>   validating role. To give the user full site permissions, click the link
>   below:
>
> http://example.com/user/validate/XX/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/admin
>
> Alternatively, you may visit their user account listed above and remove them
>   from the validating role.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into logintoboggan.module you would see that this message is hard-coded and appended using the [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) function and that it's altering the  **Welcome (awaiting approval)** (user_register_pending_approval_admin) located in admin/config/people/accounts. So if you like to append the data in the middle, you can edit the said email body in the admin page but if you also like to alter the message by logintoboggan then you need to implement hook_mail_alter also.